# How to use two query clients (normal and persistent one) in tanstack-query

Tags: tanstackreact-query

I want to use two query clients: normal one for usual use cases, and persistent one to cache some queries for a long time. What is the correct implementation? Is below correct? How to use `persistent` query provider for certain queries? I guess by default `useQuery` uses the provider from the nearest content (not persistent one in my case).

```
'use client';

import { TooltipProvider } from '@/components/ui/tooltip';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'next-themes';

import { createSyncStoragePersister } from '@tanstack/query-sync-storage-persister';
import { PersistQueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query-persist-client';

export const persistQueryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      retry: false,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // 24 hours,
      staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 1, // 1 hour
    },
  },
});

export const persister = createSyncStoragePersister({
  storage: window.localStorage,
});

export const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export default function GlobalProviders({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider
      attribute='class'
      defaultTheme='system'
      enableSystem
      disableTransitionOnChange
    >
      <PersistQueryClientProvider
        client={persistQueryClient}
        persistOptions={{ persister }}
      >
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <TooltipProvider>{children}</TooltipProvider>
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </PersistQueryClientProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Also, for each query I want to specify `cache` time separately as below where the query should be stale after midnight:

```
 return useQuery(['usersStats'], queryFn, {
    cacheTime: new Date().setHours(24, 0, 0, 0) - Date.now(),
  });
```